# The object disappears when you scroll the page

Tags: google-swiffy

The file received from https://developers.google.com/swiffy/ has "body style="overflow: hidden". Why is that? Where can I read more documentation? Why "swiffy" disappears while scrolling? I put "swiffy" in the "iframe" - it works, but I do not want to use the "iframe".
Thanks!

Comment: offscreen rendering bug.
go check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32220527/5267294

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now it works! I commented out b.xj(c);

Answer (score 0):

We have just discovered this issue too. Older swiffy files converted with v7.2.0 scroll fine, but now when we create new files, the swiffy object disappears after you scroll.

I can't locate any decent information anywhere on how swiffy works.