# Swiffy runtime error bug

Tags: google-swiffy

I have noticed that the runtime engine for swiffy has updated from v7.2.0 to v7.3.0 which has created a noticeable bug for newly created converted files.

The issue is that when you publish a swiffy file to a site and then scroll it off the screen, when you try to scroll it back onto the screen it disappears off the page altogether.

I should have a link tomorrow that demonstrates an old file versus a new created file. But if anyone else has experienced this issue it would be great to know.

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Comment: offscreen rendering bug.
go check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32220527/5267294