# Swiffy converted animation breaks after going off the screen

Tags: google-swiffy

Hi,

I converted my flash movie into javascript using the Google Swiffy tool. The animation looks great, exactly as it looked when it was flash. However, if you scroll the page and make it off the screen and then back on, the animation will break. It will either freeze or totally disappear. This is my code.

https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.3.0/runtime.js

```
<div class="topflash" id="swiffycontainer">
  <script>
      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),swiffyobject, {});
      stage.start();
  </script>
 </div>
```

Is it possible to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind. i found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568985/arbitrary-google-swiffy-canvas-size-off-screen-rendering/32220527#32220527