# Reload/play swiffy containter

Tags: javascript, google-swiffy

Using js we're moving the swiffy code from an iframe into the parent window, but this displays a blank canvas.  If however I manually edit the dom element by adding a child div this displays the creative.  So it appears the canvas is not being redrawn/initialised after being moved.  Any help appreciated.
http://www.theinterestingtimes.co.uk/news/?google_preview=63rGsskL8JYYq_brrwUwq5KhtwWIAYCAgKDT282b7AE&iu=154725070&gdfp_req=1&lineItemId=1988080950&creativeId=82671279390

ps. I've tried changing div's display (to force it to redraw) but this doesn't appear to work not does appending child div

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32220527/1785437
Ist says it is an offscreen rendering bug.
It helped me to solve the same problem.

**Edit**:
Original Answer by [Robert Chou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5267294/robert-chou)

> If your swiffy runtime version is 7.3, you can hack the js directly.
>
> Just remove or comment "b.xj(c);" in g.Tp() function. I don't care any
>   advantage of offscreen rendering. At least, it works now.

This "b.xj(c);" only appear once in `swiffy-runtime.js` so it is easy to "fix".